# How to Get last 5 Days Data with all Fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDb and would appreciate some help with this query. I wrote the following aggregation pipeline with Get last 5 days data based on date field  but small issue all data is comming how to get only 5 days data and sum of consumption any one please any one suggest me.

```
    {
    "timeId" : ISODate("2018-09-10T16:40:08.817Z"),
    "vendor" : "CIMCON",
    "slcId" : "123450"
    "mongoStreetLightChildVo" : {
        "deviceType" : "L",
        "totalStreetLights" : 3.0,
        "totalConsumptionMtd" : "2"
        "mongoStreetLightChildVo1s" : [ 
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-01T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 27.0,
                "burnHours" : 24.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-02T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 2.0,
                "burnHours" : 24.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-03T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 287.0,
                "burnHours" : 20.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-04T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 209.0,
                "burnHours" : 2.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-05T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 243.0,
                "burnHours" : 4.0
            },
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-06T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 254.0,
                "burnHours" : 4.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-07T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 235.0,
                "burnHours" : 24.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-08T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 62.0,
                "burnHours" : 24.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-09T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 2.0,
                "burnHours" : 23.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-10T02:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 26.0,
                "burnHours" : 27.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my dataset.

I use this to get the Last 5 days data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{
    "mongoStreetLightChildVo.mongoStreetLightChildVo1s.date": 
    {
        $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
    }
}
},
{$project:{
   "mongoStreetLightChildVo.mongoStreetLightChildVo1s.date":1,
   "mongoStreetLightChildVo.mongoStreetLightChildVo1s.consumption":1


}}
])
```

how to get only 5 days data

My required output is:

```
  {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-05T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 243.0,
                "burnHours" : 4.0
            },
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-06T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 254.0,
                "burnHours" : 4.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-07T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 235.0,
                "burnHours" : 24.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-08T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 62.0,
                "burnHours" : 24.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-09T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 2.0,
                "burnHours" : 23.0
            }, 
             {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-10T02:40:08.817Z"),
                "consumption" : 26.0,
                "burnHours" : 27.0
            }
```

Comment: Try `db.collection.aggregate({"$project":{"total":{"$let":{"vars":{"f":{"$filter":{"input":"$mongoStreetLightChildVo.mongoStreetLightChildVo1s","cond":{"$gte":["$$this.date",new Date((new Date().getTime() - (5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))]}}}},"in":{"$sum":"$$f.consumption"}}}}})`

Comment: I am try this code but  trow error Error:
TypeError: db.STREETLIGHTSINSTANT_MONTH.aggregeate is not a function :
@(shell):1:1 @ Veeram

Comment: Try again. change to aggregate. typo there.

Comment: iam try this code  output is  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b96154a864585ef82b684a2"),
    "total" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b961599864585ef82b684a3"),
    "total" : 10.0
} iam not getting required out put my required output  @  Veeram

Comment: required output is:{
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-11T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "burnHours" : 4.0
            },{
                "date" : ISODate("2018-09-10T16:40:08.817Z"),
                "burnHours" : 8.0
            },etc last 5 days data @Veeram

Comment: Can you add the required output to the post ? You are asking for sum of consumption but your output shows burnHours. Which one it is ? If it is burnHours just change from consumption to burnHours in the aggregate query.

Comment: Please take some time when you post question. It is very important to get all the details right so it will save us from going back and forth.

Comment: sorry  Veeram  by mistake i mention required out put please check @  Veeram

Comment: Its okay. Based on your output you need `db.collection.aggregate({"$project":{"data":{"$filter":{"input":"$mongoStreetLightChildVo.mongoStreetLightChildVo1s","cond":{"$gte":["$$this.date",new Date((new Date().getTime() - (5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))]}}}}})`

Comment: iam try this code get data  data like {
    "data" : []
}

/* 2 */
{
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-09-06T16:40:08.817Z"),
            "consumption" : 2.0
        }{
     }  
    ]
} @ Veeram

Comment: if any posible my required output @  Veeram

Comment: That is not possible. Query I have provided only filters the document. It doesn't change the format. I have verified the query and it returns the expected output.

Comment: ok thanks for supporting , in front of the output to display result this type empty data like {
    "data" : []
} if any possible remove this @  Veeram

Comment: Yw. add the $match stage to filter the empty array after $project stage. Something like `{$match:{"data.0":{$exists:true}}}`